# How to calculate gradients in Tensorflow c++ API based on a saved graph

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to calculate gradients using Tensorflow c++ API. I got tf.gradients work in Python API:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.Variable([[5.0,1.0,2.0]], name='a')
    b = tf.Variable([[9.0,2.0,0.0]], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, tf.transpose(b), name="c") 
    deriv = tf.gradients(c,a, name="deriv")  #\partial c/\partial a

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(deriv)) 

    #### get the tensor by name ####
    tmp = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("deriv/c_grad/MatMul:0")
    print(sess.run(tmp))

    #### save graph ####
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, './', 'graph.pb', as_text=False)
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, './', 'graph.pbtxt', as_text=True)


    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, "variable", global_step=0)
```

I got the correct answer from both `print(sess.run(deriv))` and `print(sess.run(tmp))` and got graph.pb generated. Then I tried to use the following c++ code to load the graph and do the gradient calculation in a similar manner as I did in Python.

```
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/framework/ops.h"

void checkStatus(const tensorflow::Status& status) {
  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    namespace tf = tensorflow;

    tf::Session* session;
    tf::Status status = tf::NewSession(tf::SessionOptions(), &session);
    checkStatus(status);

    tf::GraphDef graph_def;
    status = ReadBinaryProto(tf::Env::Default(), "graph.pb", &graph_def);
    checkStatus(status);

    status = session->Create(graph_def);
    checkStatus(status);

    tf::Input::Initializer xi({1.0,2.0,-6.0});
    tf::Input::Initializer yi({9.0,2.0,0.0});
    std::vector<std::pair<tf::string, tf::Tensor>> input_tensors = {{"a", xi.tensor}, {"b", yi.tensor}};
    std::vector<tf::Tensor> output_tensors;
    status = session->Run(input_tensors, {"deriv/c_grad/MatMul"}, {},  &output_tensors);
    checkStatus(status);

    tf::Tensor output = output_tensors[0];
    auto out = output.vec<float>();
    std::cout << out(0) << " " << out(1) << " " << out(2) <<  std::endl;
    session->Close();
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation ran smoothly but I got a runtime error:

Internal: Output 0 of type double does not match declared output type float for node _recv_b_0 = _Recvclient_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=-3399984051910545345, tensor_name="b", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"

Besides "deriv/c_grad/MatMul", I also tried all other names related to "deriv" in graph.pbtxt but none of them works.

So, my question is how to refer to the node of gradient calculation? It seems Python accepts "deriv/c_grad/MatMul" but c++ does not. I am also wondering whether there is any more general way to do that. As I may differentiate a neural network output instead of a dot product w.r.t. an input tensor in the future, `MatMul` will not be the last step anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't initialize your **yi** input tensor properly.

```
Internal: Output 0 of type double does not match declared output type float
for node _recv_b_0 = _Recvclient_terminated=true,
recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
send_device_incarnation=-3399984051910545345, 
tensor_name="b",tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"
```

In your sample you initialize **yi** as doubles:

```
tf::Input::Initializer yi({9.0,2.0,0.0});
```

You should probably just try (note added **f**'s):

```
tf::Input::Initializer yi({9.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f});
```